# newpx font does not use palatino numbers&mathrm but CM numbers&mathrm

Tags: fonts, math-fonts

I use `XeLaTeX`

You can see that `4 3 ball` are CM fonts. How to fix this?

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{newpxtext}
\usepackage{newpxmath}

\begin{document}
    Hello world, 2022.
    \begin{equation}
        V_{\mathrm{ball}} = \frac{4\pi}{3}r^3
    \end{equation}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: What gives you that idea?

Comment: you can see that numbers in text are newpxfont but numbers in equations are in Computer modern

Comment: No, I checked `\showoutput` and get `\OT1/zplTLF/m/n/10 4` and `\OT1/zplTLF/m/n/10 3`

Comment: Perhaps you should note on your question that you are **not** using `pdflatex`!!! Using `pdflatex` the fonts are correct. But with say `lualatex` the font setup is different, not sure if those two packages adjusts themself.

Comment: Yes,I use xelatex

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`newtxtext` shoots itself in the foot by loading `fontspec` in the package *after* its own definition of `\rmdefault` which means that it overwrites `\rmdefault` again and then delaying the fontsetup to the end of preamble. This means that `\rmdefault` is `lmr` when `newtxmath` is loaded and so the operator font is wrong.

If you load fontspec earlier it works again:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{newpxtext}
\usepackage{newpxmath}

\begin{document}
    Hello world, 2022.
    \begin{equation}
        V_{\mathrm{ball}} = \frac{4\pi}{3}r^3
    \end{equation}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Update 2022-07-07: fontspec is not conpatible woth ctex and says: `Package fontspec: The font "Noto Sans Mono CJK SC Bold" cannot be (fontspec) found.` need to add `\defaultfontfeatures{}` after loading newtxtext and newtxmath